# Json Parsing in Android Application

Tags: android, json, parsing

After completing the XML SAX Parsing now I am working on JSON Parsing in my application. Here I am providing you the Json

```
Response : {"menu": {
              "id": "file",
              "value": "File",
              "popup": {
                "menuitem": [
                  {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
                  {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
                  {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
                ]
              }
            }}
```

Now I had referred one example of Json Parsing in which they had created a jString Object and I had a doubt in that particular line which is as under :

```
private String jString = "{\"menu\":    {\"id\": \"file\", \"value\": \"File\", \"
```

Can anyone make me clear about it please. 
The Link of the Complete Example is as Under:

http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a JSON object from the response like this (I assume you know how to take care of the response):

```
String[] file = null;

/* Make a JSON object from your response, yourResponse is a String containing
the whole response */
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(yourResponse);

/* Your "menu": array from your response */
JSONArray infoArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("menu"); 

/* If the array contains multiple items, loop it
through the infoArray's size */
for (int i = 0; i < infoArray.length(); i++) {  
        try {    
          //Get the value inside "id"
          file[i] = infoArray.getJSONObject(i).optString("id");                  
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private String jString = "{\"menu\":    {\"id\": \"file\", \"value\": \"File\", \"
```

They are just creating a string that will look like:

```
{"menu":    {"id": "file", "value": "File", .. etc.
```

They use `\` because the `"` char has to be escaped.

Comment: My doubt is that how long we have to type the string? I mean do we have to type the full response in the Object we create? Because my response is quite very long compared to the one in Example.