# Fetching Json using android from webservice

Tags: android, json

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clcik);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                List list = new ArrayList<>();
                String url ="http://abcd.abcd.com/api/SearchJob?                           limit=5&jobkeyword=oil&countrytext=United%20Kingdom&location=London%20[Greater%2        0London]&apikey=1111111111&siteid=1";
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                try{

                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient() ;
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);
                    InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    is.close();
                    String json = sb.toString();
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("jobslist");
                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String jobtitle = c.getString("jobtitle");
                        list.add(jobtitle);
                        Log.d("list", jobtitle);
                    }




                    ArrayAdapter<List> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<List>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);

                    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.jsonlist);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                }catch(Exception e){

                }

            }
        });




    }
    }
```

This is my MainActivity code. i am trying to fetch data from a webservice but i am not able to display it .

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >



    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click me"
        android:id="@+id/clcik"

        />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/jsonlist"

        ></ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

This my xml code.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.practice.android.json"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my manifest file .Can someone Please Help me out.Forget about the url its just an example. is something wrong with my code?? i am using sdk 23 and the Http Methods are decripted but i  have seen people tell that it still works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Json Parsing in Android Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819273/json-parsing-in-android-application)

Comment: so what's the problem? are you getting errors? worst thing is using empty `catch` like this `catch(Exception e){ }` add `e.printStacktrace();` and see what's going on

Comment: no i am not gettng any errors

Comment: use `AsyncTask` for communication between your server and mobile app, or any sort of network communicaiton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your trying to make a web request on the UIThread which in android is not allowed.

you need to make any web requests in a separate thread. Looking at your code you are using the data in the web request to build up a ListView.

take a look at the following [link](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/01/android-async-listview-jee-and-restful.html) to see how you can do this.