# Android Login Registration

Tags: android

I'm working on a login and registration activity using php mysql in Android. I tried testing the registration part but it's not working. My php files have been tested and they're working fine. I suspected my problem might be the url I've provided, but it works in the browser. When the details are entered in the registration form, clicking submit button does nothing.

Here's my code:
Login.java

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


}


public void userLogin(View view)
{

}

public void userReg(View view)
{
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Registration.class));
}
```

}

Registration.java

```
public class Registration extends Activity {

EditText ETname, ETusername, ETpassword;
String name, username, userpass;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);


    ETname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.newUsername);
    ETusername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.newUserid);
    ETpassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.newUserpassword);


}

public  void reg(View view)
{
    name=ETname.getText().toString();
    username=ETusername.getText().toString();
    userpass=ETpassword.getText().toString();
    String method= "register";
    BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
    backgroundTask.execute(method,name,username,userpass);
    finish();

}
```

}

BackgroundTask.java

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

Context ctx;
BackgroundTask(Context ctx)
{
    this.ctx=ctx;

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params)
{
    String reg_url="http://127.0.0.1/webapp/register.php";
    String login_url="http://127.0.0.1/webapp/login.php";
    String method= params[0];
    if(method.equals("register"))
    {
        String name=params[1];
        String user_name=params[2];
        String user_pass=params[3];

        try {
            URL url = new URL(reg_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter= new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("user","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("user_pass","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_pass,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            os.close();
            InputStream is= httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            is.close();
            return "Registration Success...";


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Toast.makeText(ctx,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sending the data in the correct order to the server ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Json Parsing in Android Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819273/json-parsing-in-android-application)

Comment: Yes, It's in the right order @RakshitNawani

Comment: I have'nt used json, just php which returns echo statement@AjayPandya

Answer (score 0):

you may not need to convert your `KEY` to `encode` just value needs to be `encoded` So,

Change this

```
String data = URLEncoder.encode("user","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("user_pass","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_pass,"UTF-8");
```

To

```
String data = "user"="+URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        "user_name"+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"+"user_pass"+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_pass,"UTF-8");
```

See if this work out for you.

Answer (score 0):

You said you click the submit button, maybe you are not calling the onClick properly.
Have you tried getting a reference to the button in the Activity via findViewById(R.id.button)?
Also try printing the url to make sure it's in the right format.